# Reference sObject Fields dynamically from a string value

Tags: apex

Is it possible to reference the fields of an sObject (opportunity in this example) dynamically from a string value?

For example, take the following code:

```
 for(Opportunity o: oppList) {
      for(String s : strList) {
           // I'd like to set the opportunity field values based on the string 
           // value that contains the API name of the opportunity field
      }
 }
```

So, the variable `strList` contains the opportunity API field names. I'm trying to clear some fields on the opportunity in a before update trigger, but I have to access the field names dynamically in the `strList`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the "get" and "put" methods allow reading and writing fields by their field names:

```
for(Opportunity record: records) {
  for(String fieldName: fieldNames) {
    Object value = record.get(fieldName); // Get a field value!
    record.put(fieldName, null); // Clear a field!
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox Worked perfectly!!